# Getting org/testng/TestNG : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 on maven test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven-testNG project.Below is my testNG dependency in pom.xml. JAVA_HOME is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67` also set eclipse compiler compilance level as 1.7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

when I right click project->Run As->Maven Test , then I get above version error. When I run individual test as TestNg Test, then test executes successfully . Where could be the problem

Comment: You are manually configuring Eclipse here, but apparently this is a mavenized project and in mavenized projects, the poms should dictate the settings that are pushed to the Eclipse projects. Are you sure the maven poms don't declare Java 8 compilation levels in the compiler plugin configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major version of 52 points to Java8, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file, so you need to upgrade your JDK.

Comment: If I am using JDK 1.7 (Java7) what would be the version of testNG?

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/index.html says JDK7 should be sufficient(weird). There's no table with requirements, only for the latest version. Best you ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try mvn -version to find out which Java is used by Maven. 
You may have to define the right Java-Version in your pom.xml too.